# updating one table in database 1 to a table in database 2 receiving converting data error

Tags: sql, casting

I have two tables in different databases. The table to update is `jomast` in the database where the SQL code lives. The second table is in Scheduling_data DBO as `testtable`.

Additionally, I know that once I get the data from the source table into the correct format that I will need to use wildcards as the incoming data is stated as, e.g. `32`, while the receiving table has the data as a `varchar10` showing as, e.g. `00031-0000`.

So I can do one of two things, either cast the change in the code, listed below, as the link or create an additional column in the source testtable and write code to change the incoming column to another column changing the format from; 31 to 00031-000.

Here is my code that is erroring out with a `8114 message not able to convert varchar to float`.

```
update jomast
set frel_dt = T2.releasedate
from Scheduling_Data.dbo.testtable as T2
where cast (jomast.fjobno as varchar(20)) = T2.job
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and using `FROM` with an `UPDATE` statement is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my cast was in the wrong location. Moved it to the T2 data and it worked. Would like help on the other part of this post though.